# Why are transactions recorded in GA with a (not set) landing page

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

Our website is seeing around 30% of transactions being recorded as Google/organic as the source/medium, however the landing page is showing (not set) and no sessions/average session duration data is being recorded - just the transaction and ecommerce revenue.

I suspect this is actually paid search traffic, but the utm tracking is being dropped somewhere. This is the website https://www.relish-life.com/ I'm not sure what's causing the (not set) to appear as the landing page.

Comment: Are you sure you track all the pages? I believe you have serious tracking problems

Comment: Yes, we've added Google Analytics through tag manager for all pages

Comment: And are you sure it's working fine?